# Retaining Text in Find Replace in Sublime Text

Tags: regex, notepad++, sublimetext3, wildcard, boost-regex

I have strings as follows

- 5V6A 6Q2A 6Q 5Q
- FA 7A EQ2A 799Q
- M Y77A279791
- V59 2 5A266
- Q7Q E7Q 7 7AQ2A 7A29

I identify them using following in Find Option

```
\w.+\d.+(\w+( |$))+
```

My problem is that I want to replace it with same, but add a "@" symbol afterwards. I want find-replace in Sublime Text / Notepad++. I want to retain what I find, replace with same, but with a "@" at the end of it. So at the end, I want it to be as follows after replacement.

- 5V6A 6Q2A 6Q 5Q @
- FA 7A EQ2A 799Q @
- M Y77A279791 @
- V59 2 5A266 @
- Q7Q E7Q 7 7AQ2A 7A29 @

Please help with replace.

Example of Data I want to find them in

```
5V6A 6Q2A 6Q 5Q
Ms.Elena O Peery
Abell (Baltimore)
$Six Million  One Hundred Thirty Thousand Seven Hundred Thirty Nine AND Twenty Six%
Twenty Nine Years AND Seven.One%
(Purchase Value Reduction 16.47%)
(Monthly Principal Reduction 7.59%)
(Total Interest Reduction 17.81%) 
Mr. Guy L Pittman   
E97 99A2A 7Q 9A2999Q

 Q5A2A5 6 6A 5 767Q 
 Mrs.Margaret E No Lents
 Juction(Portland) 
 $Seven Million Nine Hundred Eighty Six Thousand Three Hundred Twenty Three     AND Seventeen%
 Seventeen Years AND Seven.Eight%
(Purchase Value Reduction 2018%)
(Monthly Principal Reduction 1036%)
(Total Interest Reduction 14.87%) 
Ms.Edna R Messerly 
7A2YA2AQ27A 7A27AQ2
```

Comment: What's the rule for matching above strings ?

Comment: \w.+\d.+(\w+( |$))+  seems to work mostly. You can suggest if there are better ones :)

Comment: I mean they are just Upper case characters, number and space at random positions. Check my [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tN2tA6/2). Is this what  you are looking for ?

Comment: searching `$` and replacing with ` @` works prefectly in notepad++ for all samples - but i doubt a bit that that's what you want

Comment: @SebastianProske I dont think those strings occur at end of lines, i think they can be in between as well

Comment: @noob , your solution seems to work. thanks. but that it has other words between them, so they are getting replaced too, for example :
    
    F66 64 7376 7  "@" - I want @ here
    Mr.Howard M Adams
    Jonesville,AK 
    $Six Million Three Hundred Sixty Seven Thousand Fifty AND     Nineteen%
    Thirteen Years AND Nine.Five%
    (Purchase Value Reduction 19.47%)
    (Monthly Principal Reduction 5.56%)
    (Total Interest Reduction 10.47%) 
    Ms.Kathryn J Mite 
    V9A27AQ2M Y M Y99 7 "@" - I want @ here

Comment: Please provide additional strings you want to **match** and some you do **not want to be matched**. As the question stands, it's somewhat unclear.

Comment: I still don't get the criteria for making up the regex but if your regex works fine then search for `(\w.+\d.+(\w+( |$))+)` and replace with `\1 @` in notepad++

Comment: @VIVEK: I think you should give proper details in the question. I can see that you are a new user on this site. Without details one is not going to assume anything else.

Comment: @ritesht93 : It Worked. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just posting it as an answer to mark the question solved.

I still don't get the criteria for making up the regex but if your regex works fine then search for `(\w.+\d.+(\w+( |$))+)` and replace with `\1 @` in notepad++

Comment: This is ***very*** ineffective and likely to fail soon because of the nested quantifiers. Your expression needs [**19000 (sic!) steps**](https://regex101.com/r/eT7pA7/4) for a rather short text - what is it supposed to do when handling a *real* text?

Comment: @Jan Yes I know, regex was not formed by me, the input text wasn't specified, also the regex matching criteria wasnt specified until very late after OP edited the question, i posted this answer as a comment as a quick fix

Answer (score 0):

In Sublime Text try this `(\w.+\d.+(?:\w+(?: |$))+)` in `find` box and this in `$1 @` `replace` box.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the following "criteria" might help:

```
^((?>\h?(?>[A-Z0-9]+)\h?)+)$
# ^ and $ - bind to beginning and end of the line in multiline mode
# the rest matches uppercase letters and digits 
# plus an optional whitespace at the beginning / end of the line
# ... and puts them in atomic groups
```

See an [example on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/eT7pA7/5).